# Is there a way to detect collisions between 2 SKSpriteNodes but allow them to overlap

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I don't think there is a way to do this, but is there a way to detect when 2 SKSpriteNodes intersect with each other, but still allow them to overlap, so they don't actually bounce over each other?

I know I can just have 1 without a physics body, and then write some code to check their co-ordinates, but I thought maybe I might be missing something in Sprite Kit where I could detect this with SK methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `contactDelegate` property of the `SKPhysicsWorld` object:

```
// inside your header file

typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, CollisionCategory) {
    categoryOne = (1 << 0),
    categoryTwo = (1 << 1)
};

// inside your SKScene sub-class implementation

- (void)setupContactDelegate {
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    nodeA.categoryBitMask = categoryOne;    // nodeA is category one
    nodeA.collisionBitMask = ~categoryTwo;  // nodeA does not collide w/ category two
    nodeA.contactTestBitMask = categoryTwo; // nodeA tests for contacts w/ category two

    nodeB.categoryBitMask = categoryTwo;    // nodeB is category two
    nodeB.collisionBitMask = ~categoryOne;  // nodeB does not collide w/ category one
    nodeB.contactTestBitMask = categoryOne; // nodeB tests for contacts w/ category one
}

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    // do whatever you need to do when the contact begins
}

- (void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    // do whatever you need to do when the contact ends
}
```

You'll also need to declare your `SKScene` sub-class as implementing the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` protocol.

Here's more reference info:

- [SKScene Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKScene/physicsWorld)
- [SKPhysicsWorld Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKScene/physicsWorld)
- [SKPhysicsBody Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/SKPhysicsBody)
- [SKPhysicsContactDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContactDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/SKPhysicsContactDelegate)
- [SKPhysicsContact Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContact/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsContact/bodyA)

Comment: Yes, this is fine, but I was trying to detect contact between 1 body WITH a physics body and one without, which I don't think this allows for, don't you have to connect the contactTestBitMask to a physics body?

Comment: Yes, you need a physics body, but you can just set the body's `dynamic` to `NO` and `collisionBitMask` to `0x00000000`, and it won't interact with anything.

Comment: You have no idea how long I was searching for such a clear answer! Thanks!

Comment: Wow I totally didn't know about that ~category thingy. Thanks dude.